# Trying to paint a couple of squares

Tags: java, draw, paintcomponent

I'm new both to stack overflow and to java.

I'm trying to make a basic program to learn how to draw stuff.

First of all, this is the class that will draw the rectangles

```
impo rt javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Drawqwe extends JPanel {
 private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2d.fillRect(30, 20, 50, 50);
        g2d.fillRect(120, 20, 90, 60);
}


 @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }    


}
```

And this is the main class, where I want to call the drawqwe class to paint a couple of squares.

I just dont know what to type inside the call.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class JavaApplication27 extends JFrame{

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f = new JFrame();

    f.setTitle("ASD");
    f.setSize(1000,1000);
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setVisible(true);

    Drawqwe draws1 = new Drawqwe();

   //HERE I DONT KNOW WHAT TO TYPE INSIDE () TO MAKE IT WORK.

    draws1.paintComponent();
}
}
```

Accepting all kinds of suggestions, as this is my first post.

Comment: You need to add your `draws1` panel to the frame `f`.

Comment: You don't call `paintComponent` directly. You add the panel to the frame, before calling `setVisible()`. Once `setVisible()` is called, the panel will be painted.

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot :D